# jQuery combobox attach an on blur event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, combobox

I am referring the following url http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox
to render comboBoxes in my HTML page.
I want to attach a blur event to  my comboBox so that when a user clicks on the comboBox and then moves to the next field I can trigger a validation message.
On searching I found that there is only a select eventthat can be attached that gets triggered when you select a value from the comboBox.

HTML CODE

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Reason, new SelectList(ViewBag.SelectReason, "Key", "Value"), "", new { id = "drop2", placeholder = "Select Reason" })
```

Jquery Code:

```
  $("#drop2").blur(function () {
           // here goes your code
        alert("blur");
    });
```

Is there any way that I can trigger an onBlur event ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to attach a blur  event to  my comboBox using this

```
     $('#myDropDownName').next().find('input').blur(function () {

      //My Action
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should still have something like this in your page to be able to enable `combobox`: `<select id="combobox">`

Then, you can directly use jquery to apply `blur` event on the `select` element:

```
$("#combobox").blur(function(){
    // here goes your code
}
```

Comment: I tried the same, the event does not fire.
blur ,focus don't seem to work  for comboBoxes..

Comment: can you post your code? @AnanthKumble  make sure the id matches `$("#idOfSelect").blur(function(){`

Comment: Sorry my bad in editing code it is #drop2.. and it does not work